# How to split space delimited field into rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I found [this function](http://www.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx) which returns three rows for the following query:

```
select * from dbo.split('1 2 3',' ')
```

However, I need to use values from a field instead of '1 2 3'.

I tried:

```
select * from dbo.split(select top 1 myfield from mytable,' ')
```

But it fails saying incorrect syntax.

It doesn't have to use the function above, so feel free to recommend another function or different way to go about it. To clarify, I only need to parse the values from a single row of a single field.

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply the split(myfield) function to each row in mytable. When the split function is a table valued function the correct answer is the [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156.aspx) operator:

> The APPLY operator allows you to
>   invoke a table-valued function for
>   each row returned by an outer table
>   expression of a query.

So the answer must be:

```
select *
from mytable 
cross apply dbo.split(myfield, ' ');
```

Example:

```
create table mytable (myfield varchar(10));
insert into mytable (myfield) values ('1 2 3');
go

create function split (@list varchar(max), @delimiter char(1))
returns @shards table (value varchar(8000))
with schemabinding
as
begin
  declare @i int;
  set @i = 0;
  while @i <= len(@list)
  begin
    declare @n int;
    set @n = charindex(@delimiter, @list, @i);
    if 0 = @n
    begin
       set @n = len(@list);
    end
    insert into @shards (value) 
      values (substring(@list, @i, @n-@i+1));
    set @i = @n+1;
  end
  return;
end
go

select * 
from mytable  
cross apply dbo.split(myfield, ' ');
```

Comment: Tried your solution and it didn't work. Error returned is this: "srgspossiblevalues" (that's the name of my field) is not a recognized table hints option. I'll clarify the question to indicate that I only need to parse the values from one cell.

Comment: You are translating my example incorrectly into your code. There aren't any table hints. I've expanded my example to a full blown running code sample.

Comment: Remus -- Thanks for the reply. 

I tried using your function and get the same error. Actually, for kicks, I deleted the Split function and ran your entire code block to see if it would work. It returned the same error about table hints: "myfield" is not a recognized table hints option. 

Given my little experience with advanced sql it's very possible I'm still doing something wrong or misunderstanding your solution. Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Is it SQL 2000 by any chance? APPLY is a new operator valid only for SQL 2005 and up.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
SELECT dbo.split(myfield, ' ') AS x FROM mytable
```

Comment: You can't use table value functions like this. The OP clearly states that the function 'returns three rows', so is not a scalar.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the answer. However, it looks like Remus is right. I get this error: Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.split", or the name is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC SP_DBCMPTLEVEL 'YOUR_DB_NAME',90;
```

Should fix the problem of Remus's incompatible code. I just looked into my own db and it was set to level '80' which means it supports <= SQL 2000. After applying the procedure above, the code runs and works perfectly.

Now I just need to find out wtf relies on SQL2000 and breaks in SQL2005...AHH!

This MSDN link will help you determine whether your fn/usp/app layers will be negatively impacted: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select * from dbo.split((select top 1 myfield from mytable),' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

put the UDF around your column, example

```
SELECT dbo.split(myfield, ' ')  as SplitValue
FROM mytable
```